# UIBlurEffect not blurring entire image in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following code to blur out an image.

```
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
    let blurredEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurredEffectView.frame = imageBlur.bounds
    //blurredEffectView.alpha = 0.8
    imageBlur.addSubview(blurredEffectView)
    
    imageBlur.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: item._galleryURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))
```

However, when I run the code, I am seeing this for the first two elements in the UITableView.

[image]

When I scroll down and then back up again, they will fix...

[image]

What can be causing this bug?

Comment: I think that "imageBlur.bounds" is different when you're adding blur first time (when cell is created) and second time (when cell is dequeued). Use autolayout to align blurredEffectView inside imageBlur properly.

Comment: You should tell your readers where that code comes from. Is it in your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method? Why not provide the full method? (If there's tons of irrelevant code replace that with a comment `// irrelevant setup code deleted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the blur view in tableView cell you the view not now the exact size. So in the first create of screen it looks not okay but when you scroll down and up it recycles and know it size it becomes okay.

So you can solve it by giving size in layoutsubviews() function like

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    blurredEffectView.frame = imageBlur.bounds
}
```

Comment: You should accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: @letsCode can you accept the answer if it is worked?

Comment: @DuncanC yeah i planned two. but i have to wait a few minutes after the initial post and I forgot...